# unittest is not running my tests after reorganising file structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my structure:

```
directory/
      __init__.py (blank)
      myClass.py
      test/
             UnitTest.py
             IntegrationTest.py
             __init__.py (blank)
```

Let's use UnitTest as the example (both of them result in 0 tests). Feel free to critique my imports, I was fiddling around with it forever to import the class correctly so I can execute the UnitTest script. Also yes, I did copy a lot of code from other stack exchange questions in my search.

Before I moved to this structure, I had everything in one directory, so I know the test file works (outside of the imports)

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    file = Path(__file__).resolve()
    parent, top = file.parent, file.parents[2]

    sys.path.append(str(top))
    try:
        sys.path.remove(str(parent))
    except ValueError: # Already removed
        pass

    import directory.test
    __package__ = 'directory.test'

from myClass import myClass
import unittest
from unittest import mock

print("Running Unit Tests...")
mc = myClass(params)

def mockingResponse(*args, **kwargs):
    class MockResponse:
        def __init__(self, json_data, status_code):
            self.json_data = json_data
            self.status_code = status_code

        def json(self):
            return self.json_data

    #if/elses that return value

@mock.patch('myClass.requests.get', side_effect = mockingResponse)

class unitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    print("this should run before test call")
    def testsomefunc():
        response = mc.somefunc()
        differenceSet = set(response) ^ set(mockrespose from if/elses)
        assert len(differenceSet) == 0
    def testotherfunc():
        #7 tests in total, same layout, different mockresponse

print("is this actually running")
unittest.main()
```

Then I get this in terminal:

```
privacy:~/git/directory$ python3 -m test.UnitTest.py 
Running Unit Tests...
this should run before test call
is this actually running

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Checking online, I know it's not the issue of not having my names start with test and it's not because I have it indented wrong. Can't find much else in my search.

My only other thought is that it might be because I ran it as a module, but if I don't I have more problems with importing myClass. Of the many solutions I've tried for importing, this is the only one that has worked thus far.

Comment: I don't think the `python-requests` tag is necessary?

Comment: I suppose not. One of the methods that I tried to import classes imported the class successfully, but broke my mock, and I originally geared this question towards how to import my class in general, before rewriting it to specifically ask about my current solution.

That's one thing I hope people can keep in mind before suggesting any hacky ways to import it instead (if that's what's breaking it), that I did have problems with imports.